# List all files in a folder/drive as well as all sub-folders, recursively, hierarchically, and with folder/file size in Windows

Tags: windows, file-management

I am looking for a program that can list all files in a folder/drive as well as all sub-folders, recursively, hierarchically, and with folder/file size in Windows. The output should be saved in a text files.

Here is an example of output I would like to have:

```
C:\folder>list.bat
.
├── [1.9M]  aclArc-20080325.tgz
├── [ 64K]  aclArc-20080325.tgz.1
├── [ 15G]  backup
│   └── [ 15G]  pubmed.zip
├── [ 293]  connection_ssh2.sh
├── [ 242]  connection_ssh.sh
├── [244G]  corpora
│   ├── [ 15G]  cv_corpus_v1
│   │   ├── [ 12G]  cv_corpus_v1.tar.gz
[...]
```

---

I tried:

1) `tree` accessible natively in cmd.exe, but it doesn't have any option to display file sizes:

```
C:\folder>tree /?
Graphically displays the folder structure of a drive or path.

TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```

2) On Ubuntu, one can use `tree --du`,  for tree 1.6 and above:

> --du For each directory report its size as the accumulation of sizes of all its files and sub-directories (and their files, and so on). The total amount of used space is also given in the final report (like the 'du -c' command.) This option requires tree to read the entire directory tree before emitting it, see BUGS AND NOTES below. Implies -s.

so I tried tree.exe provided in Cygwin and gnuwin32, but both of them come with tree version 1.5. `UnxUtils.zip` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` don't contain `tree.exe`.

Comment: Maybe Cygwin is an alternative, it has a tree --du possibility.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? It might be possible without too much trouble to write this yourself in PowerShell.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I use Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: @albert I tried tree provided in Cygwin and gnuwin32, but both of them come with tree version 1.5, which doesn't have `--du`. `UnxUtils.zip` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` don't contain `tree.exe`.

Comment: You can _definitely_ 'roll your own'  in PowerShell without significant expenditure of time/effort; take a look at the Get-ChildItem cmdlet. If you aren't familiar with PowerShell, you can (and should!) spend some quality time learning it, but a script to do what you are asking for is almost-but-not-quite trivial.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, the version of Cygwin (32-bit) has version: $ tree --version
tree v1.7.0 (c) 1996 - 2014 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher, Florian Sesser, Kyosuke Tokoro

Comment: @albert good catch, thanks, on my setup cygwin was using the outdated gnuwin32's tree , not the cygwin provided tree 1.7 :)

Comment: [diruse](https://ss64.com/nt/diruse.html) is somewhat close to your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

In python the first [example in os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) would be simple to modify to give you what you need.

The example:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print(root, "consumes", end=" ")
    print(sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files), end=" ")
    print("bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files")
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

With [humandfriendly](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanfriendly) *installed with `pip install humanfriendly`* to make the friendly format of the sizes.

Modified:

```
from humanfriendly import format_size
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
from os.path import join, getsize, split

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    depth = len(split(root))
    print('--' * depth, split(root)[-1], '[%5s]' % format_size(sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files), binary=True))
    for fname in files:
        print('| '*depth, fname, '[%5s]' % format_size(getsize(join(root, fname)), binary=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

tree.exe from cygwin/gnuwin (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tree.htm) can do that, also in version 1.5 already. The option you want to consider is `-h` (for "human readable"): `tree -h`